# In LINQ to SQL, how do you pass parts of a LINQ query into a function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

Is it possible to pass parts of a linq Query into a function? 
I want create a common interface for my DAL that always uses the same query interface.   For example,

```
List<T> Get(Join j, Where w, Select s){    
    return currentDataContext<T>.Join(j).Where(w).Select(s).ToList();    
}
```

Is this sort of thing possible? I'm thinking it would be done with expression trees, but I haven't been able to find examples of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the "join" is tricky, because it is very hard to express a join - but things like where / select / orderby are pretty easy...

Really, it is just a case of combining the various LINQ methods on `IQueryable<T>`, which generally accept `Expression<Func<...>>` for some combination. So a basic select with an optional predicate would be:

```
    public IQueryable<T> Get<T>(
        Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate
        ) where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = (IQueryable<T>)GetTable(typeof(T));
        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }
```

I would tend to return `IQueryable<T>` too, since that is fully composable. If the caller wants a list, they can always use `ToList()` on it... or (for example):

```
    using(var ctx = new MyDataContext(CONN))
    {
        ctx.Log = Console.Out;
        int frCount = ctx.Get<Customer>(c => c.Country == "France").Count();
    }
```

which (using Northwind) does the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Country] = @p0
```

The problem with including the "select" (projection) in the query is that you would end up with multiple generic types. Since you often want the projection the be an anonymous type, it would then be pretty impossible to specify the projection type (anonymous) **and** the table-type, and it would not be callable.

In reality, I wonder if there is much benefit writing such a method at all. I might just stick with a base method:

```
    public IQueryable<T> Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>)GetTable(typeof(T));
    }
```

And let the caller compose it in their preferred way - perhaps with query syntax:

```
       var list = (from cust in ctx.Get<Customer>()
                   where cust.Country == "France"
                   select cust.CompanyName).Take(10).ToList();
```

Which uses:

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[CompanyName]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Country] = @p0
```

---

Alternatively, if you really do want to include the order by and projection, then an extension method is the most practical approach; then you don't need to specify the original (source) T (which is what makes it uncallable when mixed with anon-types):

```
public static class QueryExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<TProjection>
        Get<TSource, TProjection, TOrderKey>(
            this IQueryable<TSource> source,
            Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> where, // optional
            Expression<Func<TSource, TProjection>> select,
            Expression<Func<TProjection, TOrderKey>> orderBy)
    {
        if (where != null) source = source.Where(where);
        return source.Select(select).OrderBy(orderBy);
    }
}
```

Then consider a DAL method such as:

```
    public List<string> Countries()
    {
        return Customers.Get(
            x=>x.CompanyName != "",
            x=>x.Country,
            x=>x).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Which uses (again, with Northwind):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[Country]
FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CompanyName] <> @p0
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this generic class: [TableView.cs](http://blogs.msdn.com/kfarmer/archive/2007/11/13/encapsulation-and-linq-to-sql.aspx).

It basically uses a Func<TEntity, bool> delegate to apply the Where predicate:

```
//...
public TableView(DataContext dataContext, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    this.table = dataContext.GetTable<TEntity>();
    this.baseQuery = table.Where(predicate);
    this.predicate = predicate.Compile();
}
//...
```

Comment: I'm a bit concerned by that, actually. The fact that it compiles the predicate means that it will always load the entire table, then do LINQ-to-Objects over it. That is **very** inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Expression library available with Linq Examples , with this extension library you can pass linq clauses for where etc...

Download available from here 
[linq samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and pass the parameters in as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Marc Gravell♦, as usual, provided a very insightful answer, but I really think having methods that take *IQueryables* and add restrictions would work in most cases and they keep the code clearer and easily maintainable. For example:

```
//Join
public static IQueryable<IContract> AllContracts(this IQueryable<IAccount> accounts, ISession s ) {
          return from a in accounts
                 from contract in s.Query<IContract()
                 where (a.Id == contract.AccountId)
                 select contract;
    }
//Where
public static IQueryable<IContract> Active(this IQueryable<IContract> contracts) {
          return from contract in contracts
                 where (contract.Active == true)
                 select contract;
    }
```

Then you can mix and match these like this:

```
IQueryable<IContract> activeContracts = s.Query<IAccount>()
            .Where(o => o.Name == "XXX")
            .GetContracts(s)
            .Active();
```

I'm using extension methods and NHiberante's LINQ providing *Query* method here, but this could easily be rewritten without static methods and with any LINQ provider.